# Create Redis Service on Windows 10

Tags: redis, windows-10, windows-services, cygwin

I compiled the Redis from

https://download.redis.io/releases/

https://download.redis.io/releases/redis-6.0.15.tar.gz

I extracted to d:\Documents\Redis\redis-6.0.15\

I made the changes:

[image]

Using make for Windows

[image]

```
cd d:\Documents\Redis\redis-6.0.15\deps\
c:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe hiredis linenoise lua
cd ..
c:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe
```

I copied these files to folder in order to copy to another Windows10 Computer

```
d:\Documents\Redis\redis-6.0.15(Output)
λ dir
 Volume in drive D is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is 0E84-F989

 Directory of d:\Documents\Redis\redis-6.0.15(Output)

07/30/2021  10:47 PM    <DIR>          .
07/30/2021  10:47 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/22/2020  01:59 PM         3,556,388 cygwin1.dll
07/30/2021  10:06 PM           358,501 lua.exe
07/30/2021  10:06 PM           290,777 luac.exe
07/30/2021  10:07 PM         1,068,225 redis-benchmark.exe
07/30/2021  10:07 PM         6,429,631 redis-check-aof.exe
07/30/2021  10:07 PM         6,429,631 redis-check-rdb.exe
07/30/2021  10:07 PM         1,380,727 redis-cli.exe
07/30/2021  10:07 PM         6,429,631 redis-sentinel.exe
07/30/2021  10:07 PM         6,429,631 redis-server.exe
07/21/2021  01:07 PM            85,560 redis.conf
07/21/2021  01:07 PM            10,744 sentinel.conf
              11 File(s)     32,469,446 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  23,759,249,408 bytes free

d:\Documents\Redis\redis-6.0.15(Output)
λ
```

I was testing by console, and Works great!

Server!

[image]

Client!

[image]

In the other machine, I copied the previous files to this directory `C:\Programs\RedisWindows10\` and tested from CMD and all works like expected! Changing port to `6380` in the **`redis.conf`** file.  And testing from `redis-cli.exe -p 6380`.

Now I would like to create a Service:

**`SC CREATE RedisWindows binpath="C:\Programs\RedisWindows10\redis-server.exe"`** and How I must to include the **`redis.conf`** file?

I was checking if is possible to start the service without the configuration file (using default settings)...

`net start "RedisWindows"` and I got:

```
The service is not responding to the control function.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.
```

MY QUESTIONS!

- **How I must to include the **`redis.conf`** file?**
- **How Solve the problem of the 2186 error?**

Comment: See `/usr/share/doc/Cygwin/cygrunsrv.README` for installing Cygwin programs as services

Comment: https://web.mit.edu/cygwin/cygwin_v1.3.2/usr/doc/Cygwin/cygrunsrv.README Interesting!